# Removing some unwanted elements from the vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector that consists of some numbers in the following way:

```
A = [153 244 253 353 453 530 653 ...]
```

The pattern is that there is always `153,253,353,...,2353` (these represent time i.e. `1:53am,...11:53pm`) for a day. In between these *53 numbers there are some numbers that I don't wish to keep them. For example between 353 and 453, a 433 appears which needs to be removed from the vector. So the final result I wish to get is vector

```
A = [153 253 353 ...2353]
```

(of course in the original vector I have, this pattern for one day is repeated for a whole year).

Any thought on how to do this?

I would really appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep only the 53'' of each hour:

```
idx = ismember(A,53:100:2353);
A(idx)
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative (and possibly faster) answer to Oleg is to use the modulus operator:

```
A((mod(A,100))==53)
```

Comment: +1 You can time it, and post the results. Also, the `()` around `mod()` are unnecessary.